# Docker-compose problem copying MySQL config in CircleCI

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, circleci

The following works fine on a local machine, but fails when checked into CircleCI:

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
    - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./docker/mysql/mysqld.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
```

There is a file at ./docker/mysql/mysqld.cnf under the checked out project.

The error shown on CircleCi is:

> ERROR: for proj-server_mysql_1  Cannot start service mysql: b'oci
>   runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process
>   caused "process_linux.go:368: container init caused
>   \"rootfs_linux.go:57: mounting
>   \\\"/home/circleci/max/proj-server/docker/mysql/mysqld.cnf\\\"
>   to rootfs
>   \\\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/4a9af90d342b491ae92af5a88360d2e34fce0d21c15f8a648767e89fb51aa\\\"
>   at
>   \\\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/4a9af90d342b491ae92af5a88360d2e34fce0d21c15f8a648767e89fb51aa/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf\\\"
>   caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\""\n: Are you trying to mount a
>   directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host
>   path exists and is the expected type'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's not possible to use volume mounting with the docker executor, but with using the machine executor it's possible to mount local directories to your running Docker containers. You can learn more about the machine executor [here on our docs page](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/executor-types/#using-machine).

https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007324514-How-can-I-mount-volumes-to-docker-containers-

Comment: Well that's an unfortunate + confusing constraint. Thanks for pointing it out.